# If I know my current $v_x$ and $v_y$ and I supply a force and a direction, how do I update the velocities?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vectors, physics

Known quantities: Initial position $x_i, y_i$, initial velocity components $V_{ix}$ and $V_{iy}$, and mass $m$.

I can apply a force $F$ pushing me towards arbitrary point $P$, and then I must update the velocities accordingly the next time unit. (This is all for a game AI).

My attempt:

If I choose some point $P$ with coordinates $x_f$ and $y_f$ then the angle $\theta$ formed is part of the expression $\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{\Delta x}{d} = \frac{x_f-x_i}{d}$ where $d = \sqrt{(x_f-x_i)^2 + (y_f-y_i)^2}$.

The force applied relates to $F = ma$ so I can solve for $a = \frac{F}{m}$.

Now somehow I have to update the velocity components. We have $\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{V_{fx}}{V_f}$ (velocity in the $x$ direction over velocity in the diagonal pointing to $P$). And in general we have $V_i + a = V_f$.

I'm a little bit lost for how to update the velocities, for example solving for $V_{fx}$.

If I set the cosine stuff equal to each other we get

$$\frac{\Delta x}{d} = \frac{V_{fx}}{V_f}$$

So that means $\displaystyle V_{fx} = \frac{V_f \cdot \Delta x}{d} = \frac{(V_i + a) \cdot \Delta x}{d}$

At this point I feel like I am getting way off track and I could use some help getting it right.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained in the main body, typing the whole question in the body instead of just leaving it in the title, and explain the whole situation, the meaning of the symbols and variables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of being downvoted and rebuffed as waffling, I believe it would be useful for the OP and anyone encountering this question as a result of a search on similar terms, to look at a quick summary on the simplest way to numerically simulate the effect of forces on a point-like object.

(Why point-like? So that we can ignore any internal structure.)

First thing to realize, is that in numerical simulations, time is discretized to short intervals. Often, the intervals are of fixed (game-time) duration, to simplify the math involved. The key thing, however, is to realize that each step does not correspond to one instance of simulated continuous time, but to an *interval*. In mathematical terms, we need to *integrate* the instantaneous effects over the interval, to calculate (approximate) the effects during that interval.

Let's assume that for each object, at the start of each time step, we know their location/position vector $\vec{x}$, their velocity vector $\vec{v}$, and the sum of all forces that apply to it for the duration of the time step (about to be simulated), $\vec{F}$. If you have more than one force, you simply sum their vector components together. Let's use $\tau$ to describe the duration of the time step.

The simulated object has momentum $\vec{p} = m \vec{v}$, where $m$ is the mass of the object. If the mass of the object and the force acting on the object stay constant during the time step, then according to [Newton's second law of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_second_law#Impulse),
$$m \vec{a} = \vec{F} \iff \vec{a} = \frac{1}{m} \vec{F}$$
where $\vec{a}$ is the acceleration during the time step. Noting that
$$\vec{v}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \vec{a}(\tau) d \tau = \vec{v}(0) + \frac{t}{m} \vec{F}$$
and that
$$\vec{x}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \vec{v}(\tau) d \tau = \vec{x}(0) + \vec{v}(0) t + \vec{F} \frac{t^2}{2 m}$$

In discrete time units, this means that
$$\vec{x} \leftarrow \vec{x} + \vec{v} \tau + \vec{F} \frac{\tau^2}{2 m}$$
and
$$\vec{v} \leftarrow \vec{v} + \frac{\tau}{m} \vec{F}$$

In pseudocode in 3D:

```
Timestep:
    Let  px, py, pz  be the location of the object
                     at the start of the timestep
    Let  vx, vy, vz  be the velocity of the object
                     at the start of the timestep
    Let  fx, fy, fz  be the sum of forces acting on
                     the object during the timestep
    Let  m           be the mass of the object
    Let  t           be the duration of the timestep

    Let  c1 = 0.5*t*t/m
    Let  c2 = t/m

    px = px + t*vx + c1*fx
    py = py + t*vy + c1*fy
    pz = pz + t*vz + c1*fz

    vx = vx + c2*fx
    vy = vy + c2*fy
    vz = vz + c2*fz

    # Timestep simulated for this object!
```

If the mass of the object changes during the timestep, for example like in a rocket or some kind of thruster, we should use
$$m(t) \vec{a}(t) = \vec{F}(t) + \vec{u}(t) \frac{d m}{d t}$$
where $u$ is the velocity vector of the exhaust, and $\frac{d m}{d t}$ is the rate of change of mass, negative for exhaust.
I do believe the continuous-time solution for $\vec{a}(t)$ (with constant force $\vec{F}$) is
$$\vec{a}(t) = \frac{\vec{F} + w \vec{u}}{m_0 + w t}$$
where mass changes as $m(t) = m_0 + w t$; that integrates to
$$\vec{v}(t) = \vec{v}(0) + \left ( \vec{u} + \frac{\vec{F}}{w} \right ) \log \left ( \frac{t w}{m_0} + 1 \right )$$
and again to
$$\vec{x}(t) = \vec{x}(0) + \left( \vec{F} \left ( \frac{t}{w} + \frac{m_0}{w^2} \right ) + \vec{u} \left ( t + \frac{m_0}{w} \right ) \right ) \log \left ( \frac{t w}{m_0} + 1 \right ) + t \left ( \vec{v}(0) - \vec{u} \right ) - \vec{F}\frac{t}{w}$$
At the limit $w = 0$, these simplify to the constant-mass functions earlier above. So, the pseudocode to implement a time step when the mass of the object changes, would be

```
Timestep:
    Let  px, py, pz  be the location of the object
                     at the start of the timestep
    Let  vx, vy, vz  be the velocity of the object
                     at the start of the timestep
    Let  fx, fy, fz  be the sum of forces acting on
                     the object during the timestep
    Let  ux, uy, uz  be the velocity of the exhaust
    Let  m           be the mass of the object
                     at the start of the timestep
    Let  w           be the rate of change of mass
                     (negative if exhaust)
    Let  t           be the duration of the timestep

    c0 = t / w
    c1 = m / w
    c2 = log(1 + t*w/m)

    px = px + (fx*(c0 + c1/w + ux*(t + c1))*c2 + t*(vx - ux) + fx*c0
    py = py + (fy*(c0 + c1/w + uy*(t + c1))*c2 + t*(vy - uy) + fy*c0
    pz = pz + (fz*(c0 + c1/w + uz*(t + c1))*c2 + t*(vz - uz) + fz*c0

    vx = vx + (ux + fx/w)*c2
    vy = vy + (uy + fy/w)*c2
    vz = vz + (uz + fz/w)*c2

    m = m + t*w

    # Timestep simulated for this object!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward.  Seems like your acceleration is along $\theta$ (direction that you are aiming in $(x_f -x_i, y_f-y_i)$ and your $\Delta t=1$. So
$$V_{fx}=V_{ix}+a\cos \theta$$ and

$$V_{fy}=V_{iy }+a\sin \theta$$

Comment: They aren't necessarily aligned; the initial velocity could be pointing one way and I apply the force/acceleration another direction

Comment: This still works if your force is along the direction theta. Is it?

Comment: Ah, so P is just the point that you are aiming your force towards, is that right? So clearly, if V is not aligned in the same direction, the subscript f cannot refer to the final position. Maybe change that notation a bit? Because it suggests that you end up at P. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes P is where the force is being aimed. It seems like in practice you usually end up at P but if you're going at a weird angle at high speed then you may overshoot the destination a bit and then end up looping around until you eventually do end up at P (assuming you keep aiming there)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it should do.  Then these are the equations. I guess you could say P is what you “converge towards”.

Comment: Is there a way to compute how to adjust the force and direction so that you arrive at P in optimal time and not overshoot it by just hammering away at high force?

Comment: Yes, this is the subject of optimal control.  You could aim for optimum time or minimum distance travelled etc. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control     Look at chapter 2(bang-bang control with optimum time as the goal in this book). https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately seems to be a bit above my head! Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

If your force is known, you can have the acceleration by Newton's Law $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$. So
$$
a_x = F_x/m \qquad \text{and}  \qquad a_y=F_y/m
$$
to update the velocity you can get that by relation $\vec{a} = \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$. So
$$
\int_{v_{x_0}}^{v_{x}} dv_x = \int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{F_x}{m}  \, dt \implies v_x(t) = v_{x_0} + \int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{F_x}{m}  \, dt
$$
And same for $v_y$. The difficult part is when you evaluate the integral. Its not always have a closed form.

If however you want to update the velocity without include time as parameter (for example your force is function of position), you can use the following form. 
$$
a_x = \frac{d v_x}{dt} = \frac{d v_x}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d v_x}{dx} v_x \implies \int v_x dv_x =  \int a_x dx \implies v_x^2 = v_{x_0}^2 + 2\int_{x_0}^{x} a_x dx
$$
The formula become simple if your force is constant. In that case you'll have the form 
$$
v_x = v_{x_0} + a_x (t-t_0) \qquad \text{and} \qquad v_y = v_{y_0} + a_y (t-t_0)
$$
and 
$$
v_x^2  = v_{x_0}^2 + 2a_x (x- x_0) \qquad \text{and} \qquad v_y^2  = v_{y_0}^2 + 2a_y (y- y_0)
$$

$\textbf{EDIT :}$

In your particular case, when you hit the particle at any time $t=1,2,3,\dots$ you will change its momentum by giving it an impulse. This achieved by above equation by slighly different interpretation. We know that 
$$
\int dv_x = \int \frac{F_x}{m} dt \implies \int  m dv_x = \int F_x dt
$$
If the force is so large in the very short period of time, the equation above is become impulse momentum equation. The term in the right hand side called impulse and the left hand side is the change of momentum. After integrate we write,
$$
m v_x   = mv_{x_0} + \int_{t_0}^{t_0+\delta t} F_x dt
$$
You can give any number you like for the term $\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\delta t} F_x dt$, interpret this as the "hit" we give to the AI. The updated velocity after hitted is the velocity $v_t$. This changes is intantenously.

After you updated the velocity you can use the above equations for track down the trajectory of the particle during the gap time before it get hitted again.

Comment: +1 This is true, but you can mention that if the force is constant, then it simplified to $v_x(t) = v_{x_0} + a_x(t-t_0)$

Comment: Let me improved this.

Comment: But in my case this is just updating velocities from one time unit to the next, i.e. $t=1$. Or are you implying you can take the "full" answer and split up into several discrete updates?

Comment: That works for any $t$. Just evaluate at the value $t$ that you want.

Comment: @user504315 At every frame you add to the velocity the acceleration times $t$, the length of each frame. Do it every frame.

Comment: But if I am trying to get from A to B as fast as possible I'd be changing the direction/magnitude of F every frame, correct?

Comment: I think it will depends on the position A and B that you talking about. It depend on the special case at hand.

Comment: I mean from current position to an arbitrary destination point, I am trying to make the AI get there as quickly as possible, but this requires knowing how to update the vectors and force at each time unit

Comment: Its better to discuss this if you be specific about the force that act on the particle.

Comment: I don't understand, I already gave all relevant details I thought. What more information is needed? You know x, y, vx, vy of the AI. You can give it a direction (in the form of a point) and a force, and it will apply force in that direction and update x, y, vx, vy next turn.

Comment: To make the particle arrive as fast as possible will depend on the force acting on it. What i mean about another details is that is your system is contrained or not ? Is the force has constant magnitude or not ? Or we can control the direction and magnitude of the force ? Sth like that. Because it could different for each case. You can add the details in query above by editing it if you want. It obvious  that if you want the AI get from A to B as fast as possible then your force (that you control maybe) must always point at B every time.

Comment: You have to supply a force every turn so I think it is maybe more accurate to say that the force is constant for the duration of that time unit -- a discrete jump is made to the new position after that force is supplied. Would the force always have to point at B or wouldn't we have to resolve the vectors and figure out which direction/force would make the direction point towards B?

Comment: In that case, the force is function of time. That is $F_x = |F| \cos \theta (t)$, and $F_y = |F| \sin \theta (t)$, where $\cos \theta  = \frac{y_B - y_t}{x_B - x_t}$. Its difficult to integrate i think. It easier if we did it numerically.

Comment: I think maybe I am explaining myself poorly, this is a very discrete time-tick-by-time-tick thing, like position updates instant from one $t$ to the next $t+1$ with a force supplied each turn. I don't know how force is a function of time when I am supplying force every single turn.

Comment: You mean like we hit the particle for each unit time ?

Comment: In that case you dont nee d to integrate. You just have to use impulse momentum equation with the determined impulse. You should see other sites too. Like https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Maybe they can solve your exact problem.

Comment: Yeah, each turn we're sort of like "hitting" the AI in the direction and force that we pick -- and then the position updates. It may still have velocity left over so it'll keep going (it's possible we supply 0 force and just let it do its thing). But the important part is that we can always knock it with additional force in a particular direction. Sort of like a billiard ball moving on a table and we can jab it with the stick every second.

Comment: In that case, its become easier. I'll edit my ans to describe it.

Comment: (there is also a friction multiplier $f$ applied to the final velocity at the end of each turn so it doesn't move forever -- it'll slow down over time) -- not sure if this complicates too much

Comment: Do you mean during the movement there always a friction force  ?. Is it constant ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll accept as answer although in practice I have zero idea how to use any of that

Comment: You should consult other site for the implementation of this.

Comment: Yeah it's a constant friction force, just a multiplier that modifies the velocities at the end of each turn. i.e. after v_x and v_y are computed at the end of the turn after the force is applied, they get modified v_x -> v_x * f

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Resolve each component and integrate them separately:

$$ x= \int { [\int F_x\, dt/m + v_{xi}]} dt + x_i $$
$$ y= \int {[\int F_y\, dt/m + v_{yi}]} dt + y_i $$

Comment: What's the logic / reasoning behind this?

Comment: Handle the problem by integrating each component as if the other does not exist. One integration gives velocity plus bc, another integration the position plus bc.